# Не запускается Gulp

Tags: gulp, плагин, package

Не могу запустить gulp.

```
PS C:\Users\ItSher\Desktop\gulppack-master> gulp
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './gulp/config.js'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ItSher\Desktop\gulppack-master\gulpfile.js:24:16)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Содержимое package.json

```
{
"name": "Gulppack",
"description": "Frontend development with pleasure",
"author": "Andrey Gorokhov, Alexey Khabarovskii",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulppack.git"
},
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.2",
    "gulp-config": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-favicons": "^2.2.7",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.3.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^5.1.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.1"
}
}
```

Содержимое gulpfile.js

```
global.$ = {
gulp: require("gulp"),
gp: require("gulp-load-plugins")(),
bs: require("browser-sync").create(),
autoprefixer: require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
babel: require("gulp-babel"),
uglify: require("gulp-uglify"),
sass: require("gulp-sass"),
cleanCSS: require("gulp-clean-css"),
rename: require("gulp-rename"),
imagemin: require("gulp-imagemin"),
pngquant: require("imagemin-pngquant"),
imageminJpegRecompress: require("imagemin-jpeg-recompress"),
favicons: require("gulp-favicons"),
svgSprite: require("gulp-svg-sprite"),
replace: require("gulp-replace"),
cheerio: require("gulp-cheerio"),
newer: require("gulp-newer"),
plumber: require("gulp-plumber"),
debug: require("gulp-debug"),
watch: require("gulp-watch"),

path: {
    tasks: require("./gulp/config.js")
}
};

$.path.tasks.forEach(function(taskPath) {
    require(taskPath)();
});

// BUILD
$.gulp.task("default", $.gulp.series(
    $.gulp.parallel("html", "styles", "images", "svg", "scripts"),
    $.gulp.parallel("watch", "serve")
));
```

Comment: Файл ./gulp/config.js не может найти. Его надо создать. Возможно у вас в гите он существует как config.js.dist или config.js.example. Если так скопируйте его.

Comment: Проблема была очень глупая. Действительно не скачал файл config.js. Cпасибо за ответ.